# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Lightweight Checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

The Jenkins Pipeline plugin has a feature known as "lightweight checkout", where the master only pulls the Jenkinsfile from the repo, as opposed to the entire repo. There's a corresponding checkbox in the configuration screen. I'd like to do a lightweight checkout in a multibranch pipeline, but I'm not seeing a checkbox in the multibranch configuration screen. Any ideas how to make this happen? I noticed some closed issues that suggest this feature is available, but I wasn't able to find any specifics on how to make it happen.

Related information:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42518

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273

https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/pull/78

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked the developer, Vivek Pandey, who added the lightweight checkout feature to the multibranch plugin and he said that's the default behavior for the multibranch pipeline. Here's his response:

> For multi-branch pipeline project GitHub or Bitbucket light weight checkout is default behavior. With bitbucket it wasn’t and that’s what my PR fixed. So basically you don’t need to do any configuration, it should work out of the box.